# Can I recall a Magical Lineage Intensified Shocking Grasp with a Pearl of Power (1st)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, magus

Like a lot a Magus, I picked [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) on [Shocking Grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp/). Like a lot of Magus, I use this with [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic). So I am the owner of a [Pearl of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power/) (1st). Can I use it to recall the Intensified Shocking Grasp? AFAIK, it should work. Did I understand well?

From [metamagic feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/) errata:

> For example, an empowered burning hands uses a 3rd-level spell slot, counts as a 3rd-level spell for making concentration checks, counts as a 3rd-level spell for a magus’s spell recall or a pearl of power.

Slightly related to: [Why is Magical Lineage so great for Magus?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59095/why-is-magical-lineage-so-great-for-magus)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the feat, yes. The spell cast is a first level spell and thats the slot its using, so as long as the modified spell is not higher than first, you are able to recall it.

Comment: It’s perhaps worth noting that, though I strongly recommend not actually allowing it in a real game, the rules as written would not actually require Magical Lineage here. See the [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121334/4563).

Comment: @KRyan That one uses another ability with the spell. That use of the pearl would regain the spell, but not the ability that was used with it. Otherwise any prepared spellcasting class could gain more whatever, like arcana points and whatnot.