# Can I recall an Empowered by Empowered Magic (Su) Shocking Grasp with a Pearl of Power (1st)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, magus

My Magus reached level 6! As new arcana, I choose [Empowered Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/empowered-magic-su/).

> Benefit: The magus can cast one spell per day as if it were modified by the Empower Spell feat. This does not increase the casting time or the level of the spell.

Now my Shocking Grasp can deal 9d6 once a day.

I am the owner of a [Pearl of Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power/) (1st).

> Once per day on command, a pearl of power enables the possessor to recall any one spell that she had prepared and then cast that day. The spell is then prepared again, just as if it had not been cast.

My first reading was "Cheesy but should work". After a second thought, it seems a bit too cheesy. So, can I recall a Empowered by Empowered Magic (Su) Shocking Grasp with a Pearl of Power (1st)?

This is a following of "[Can I recall a Magical Lineage Intensified Shocking Grasp with a Pearl of Power (1st)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119573/can-i-recall-a-magical-lineage-intensified-shocking-grasp-with-a-pearl-of-power)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You can recall the spell, but you don't get to use your Empowered Magic arcana again that day.

A 1st level *pearl of power* lets you recall one first level spell. *Shocking Grasp* is one first level spell. Though you were able to treat it as an empowered spell at the moment you cast it by use of your magus arcana, the *Empowered Magic* arcana is pretty clear that the level of the spell is not affected - in all respects, you just cast a 1st level spell.

However, even though you might recover the spell slot and regain a prepared *Shocking Grasp*, the *Empowered Magic* arcana can only be used once a day. You don't regain the use of it just because you recover the spell slot you used it on. The phrasing "the spell is then prepared again, just as if it had not been cast" refers only to your selection of prepared spells, not to any other costs you may have incurred while casting the spell - you also wouldn't get an expensive material component back, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

As [Carcer’s answer covers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/121336/4563), you didn’t prepare *empowered shocking grasp*, you prepared *shocking grasp* and then used a magus arcana to change it at the time of casting. A *pearl of power* only gets you back what you prepared; any modifications you made to it after are lost, and the *pearl of power* certainly doesn’t cover the 1/day magus arcana you used.

That said, what if you did prepare *empowered shocking grasp*, that is, you used the Empower Spell metamagic feat to prepare *empowered shocking grasp* in a 3rd-level spell slot?

In that situation, I think you have a pretty solid case as far as the rules-as-written are concerned. *Pearls of power* clearly indicate that they are concerned about the *spell*’s level and metamagic is equally clear that the adjustment in spell slot does not affect the spell’s actual level (aside from Heighten Spell, obviously). There is no way to prevent a *pearl of power 1st* from recovering an *empowered shocking grasp* spell while staying true to both of those rules, and *empowered shocking grasp* is the spell that you prepared and then cast, so you should get it back complete with the metamagic.

But I don’t think you’re likely to ever find a GM who would allow it. I certainly wouldn’t. I would simply houserule *pearls of power* to be based on the level of the spell slot, rather than the spell level, and that’d be that: you would need a *pearl of power 3rd* to recover your *empowered shocking grasp*.

Comment: "empowered shocking grasp is the spell that you prepared and then cast" - no, shocking grasp is the spell he prepared. It was only empowered because he applied a special ability to it at the moment of casting. I think you have misread the question as your answer would be relevant if he was using metamagic feats which do have to be prepared ahead of time, but he's not doing that - he's using a Magus arcana which allows for enhancement at the time of casting.

Comment: @Carcer Oooh, damn, sorry, misread. You’re right. I assumed the Empower Spell metamagic was in use and this was cast from a 3rd-level spell slot to begin with. That would make for a much more interesting question...