# Do Magical Lineage, Metamagic Master and Wayang Spellhunter stack together?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, metamagic, traits

[Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/):

> Pick one spell when you choose this trait. When you apply metamagic feats to this spell that add at least 1 level to the spell, treat its actual level as 1 lower for determining the spell’s final adjusted level.

[Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master/):

> When you use the chosen spell with a metamagic feat, it uses up a spell slot one level lower than it normally would.

[Wayang Spellhunter](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wayang%20Spellhunter):

> You grew up on one of the wayang-populated islands of Minata, and your use of magic while hunting has been a boon to you. Select a spell of 3rd level or below. When you use this spell with a metamagic feat, it uses up a spell slot one level lower than it normally would.

If they stack, I could cast a Shocking Grasp with [Intensified Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic) (+1) [Empower Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic-final) (+2) with Magical Lineage (-1), Metamagic Master (-1) and Wayang Spellhunter (-1). So a 1st level Intensified Empowered Shocking Grasp. By the way, this spell should be recallable with a [Pearl of Power (1st)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119573/can-i-recall-a-magical-lineage-intensified-shocking-grasp-with-a-pearl-of-power).

**Do Magical Lineage, Metamagic Master and Wayang Spellhunter stack together?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master/) and [Wayang Spellhunter](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wayang%20Spellhunter) are the same trait…

It's unlikely that a GM will allow one creature to take *both* the [Metamagic Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/regional-traits/metamagic-master/) trait *and* the [Wayang Spellhunter](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wayang%20Spellhunter) trait. Although both are regional traits and many GMs *do* ignore the rule that says that a creature can't take more than one trait from each trait category (see [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/) on Restrictions on Trait Selection), the traits are also the *same* trait: The *d20PFSRD* renamed and changed the description of the trait Metamagic Master to remove product identity from the trait Wayang Spellhunter. There's no Metamagic Master trait in the [*Dragon Empires Primer*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8pg0?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Dragon-Empires-Primer) as per its provenance on the *d20PFSRD*, only Wayang Spellhunter.

### …But the benefits of [Magical Lineage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/magic-traits/magical-lineage/) and Waywang Spellhunter can be combined

Except in rare case, bonuses of the same type or from the same source don't stack, and, instead, only the highest bonus of the same type is applied. For example, the trait [Elven Reflexes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/elven-reflexes-half-elf/) and the trait [Reactionary](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/reactionary/) each grant a +2 *trait bonus* (the bonus's type) on initiative checks so a creature with *both* traits gains only a +2 trait bonus on initiative checks.

However, the benefits of the traits Magical Lineage and Waywang Spellhunter are *not* bonuses—and even *different* benefits—, so the two traits can work in conjunction.

This means that the benefit of the trait Magical Lineage *can* be combined with the benefit of the trait Wayang Spellhunter (i.e. Metamagic Master) to allow the creature to prepare in (or cast using) a 2nd-level slot an [intensified](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic/) [empowered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic-final/) [*shocking grasp*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp/) spell.

Comment: The phrase “bonuses that have the same names don't stack,” is sort of ambiguous—it’s bonuses that have the same *type* that don’t stack. “Type” is how the game refers to things like *trait* in a trait bonus, so you should probably use that word too. And untyped bonuses always stack unless they are from the same source. While it’s true that these aren’t technically bonuses in the first place, I think focusing more on the lack of type is better: the bonus-stacking rules seem to apply to a number of things that aren’t technically bonuses, so... but I’ve already upvoted either way.

Comment: @KRyan Much blame for any confusion can be put on the editor; the editor has made some adjustments. However, because this answer *both* dismisses the fact that the traits even grant bonuses *and* says that the different traits provide different benefits, do you really think emphasizing that the quasi-bonuses the traits provide are untyped is necessary? I mean, does this answer *really* need to delve into the *sneak attack is technically a bonus* territory?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I wasn't suggesting it should, my apologies for my own confusion. I was just suggesting a little more emphasis on “even if they were” here.

Answer (score -1):

Metamagic Master isnt the name of a trait in any Pathfidner Product. The trait with that ability listed in the source book is Wayang Spellhunter. (i.e. the two traits are the same trait)

d20pfsrd changes the names of things that are setting specific, however (at least in PFS) it does stack with Magical Lineage

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, and thanks for taking the time to help others! If you haven’t, we always recommend the [Tour], and hope you enjoy your stay.

Comment: This answer duplicates a portion of the existing accepted answer, and adds nothing uniquely useful.  We welcome you to the site, and hope that you find your time here worthwhile, but this answer in particular is not likely to get much in the way of upvotes.  Given how completely the accepted post answers the question, edits are unlikely to help this issue.  You'll be better off trying to answer a question that has not been answered, or where the given answers are inadequate.